# What occurs to you when think about "country village"?

Tags: word-usage

What occurs to you when think about "country village"? This is meant for finding out the difference bewteen Eastern and Western.

Thanks in advance！

Comment: What is your opinion? Any findings? Any research?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what you are asking?  Country village means "village in the countryside". What else could it mean? Why do you suppose it means anything else in a "Eastern" or "Western" context (I assume by Eastern you mean East Asian)

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “Eastern and Western”. Perhaps you mean Asian vs European? Please give more information.
You are right to suggest that “country village” evokes a certain sense that is more specific than just “a small settlement away from major town, cities and urban development”. 
For example in Australian English it would not be common. We use “country town” for even very small settlements. I’d expect “village” to refer to a British location, or perhaps a historic Australian location where their are old stone cottages that evoke the idea of a British village.

Comment: Hobbiton from the Lord of the Rings movies comes to mind

Comment: This is opinion-based and therefore off-topic. Everybody could answer differently as this is essentially a word-association game. Find someplace where you can run an opinion poll, maybe use a service like 'survey monkey' where you can poll your peers.